# Java: with code add a external library from a Folder

Tags: java, package, shared-libraries, addition, external

as the title states,

I have essentially the structure which looks like this:
[Structure of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vua2f.png)

There are essentialy two Folders: com and JsonJ with the jar File.

How can i take the jar File which is a library and add it as a library to the project with the help of the Code?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is loading the JAR and then loading a class from it, you will have to create a new `URLClassLoader` instance and then use that to load your class. Here's a sample way to do it.

```
public class AddToClasspathAndLoad{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws MalformedURLException{
        URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL( "file:///<absolute-path-to-jar-or-folder>" ) };
        URLClassLoader cl = ( (URLClassLoader) AddToClasspathAndLoad.class.getClassLoader() ).newInstance( urls );

        tryIt( cl );
    }

    private static void tryIt(URLClassLoader cl) {
        try {
            Class<?> c = cl.loadClass( "<fully-qualified-class-name>" );
            System.out.println( c.getName() );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```